# Matching the blink of an LED to midi music

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, led, midi

I have a function that plays a song and lights an LED corresponding to the note that is being played. when the same note is played consecutively(i.e E in bar 6) instead of the LED turning on and off for each time the note is played the LED appears to remain lit. how do i get the LED to go no and off for these notes to better synchronize with the music being played? The delay of 414 is being used as quarter notes etc.

```
void songlist (int song){
if (song==1){ 
songpage=1;
playpage=0;
mainpage=0;
tonepage=0;
lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor(4,0); 
lcd.print("ListeningTo:");// Print a message to the LCD.
lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
lcd.print(menuP1);
//Plays Mary Had a Little Lamb 
//Bar 1
 noteOn(0x90, 0x40, 100); //Quarter note: E
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x40, 0);


noteOn(0x90, 0x3E,100); //Quarter note: D
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3E, 0);



noteOn(0x90, 0x3C, 100); //Quarter note: C
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[2], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[2], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3C, 0);

noteOn(0x90, 0x3E, 100); //Quarter note: D
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3E, 0);


//Bar 2
noteOn(0x90, 0x40, 100); //Quarter note: E
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x40, 0);


noteOn(0x90, 0x40, 100); //Quarter note: E
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x40, 0);


noteOn(0x90, 0x40, 100); //Half note: E
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], LOW);
delay(828);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x40, 0);


//Bar 3
noteOn(0x90, 0x3E, 100); //Quarter note: D
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3E, 0);


noteOn(0x90, 0x3E, 100); //Quarter note: D
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3E, 0);


noteOn(0x90, 0x3E, 100); //Half note: D
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(828);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3E, 0);


//Bar 4
noteOn(0x90, 0x40, 100); //Quarter note: E
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x40, 0);


noteOn(0x90, 0x43, 100); //Quarter note: G
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x43, 0);

noteOn(0x90, 0x43, 100); //Half note: G
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(828);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x43, 0);

//Bar5
noteOn(0x90, 0x40, 100); //Quarter note: E
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x40, 0);


noteOn(0x90, 0x3E, 100); //Quarter note: D
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3E, 0);

noteOn(0x90, 0x3C, 100); //Quarter note: C
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[2], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[2], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3C, 0);

noteOn(0x90, 0x3E, 100); //Quarter note: D
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3E, 0);


//Bar 6
noteOn(0x90, 0x40, 100); //Quarter note: E
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], LOW);

delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x40, 0);


noteOn(0x90, 0x40, 100); //Quarter note: E
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);

delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x40, 0);

noteOn(0x90, 0x40, 100); //Quarter note: E
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], LOW);

delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x40, 0);

noteOn(0x90, 0x40, 100); //Quarter note: E
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], LOW);

delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x40, 0);


//Bar 7
noteOn(0x90, 0x3E, 100); //Quarter note: D
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3E, 0);


noteOn(0x90, 0x3E, 100); //Quarter note: D
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3E, 0);


noteOn(0x90, 0x40, 100); //Quarter note: E
digitalWrite(LedR[3], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[3], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[1], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x40, 0);


noteOn(0x90, 0x3E, 100); //Quarter note: D
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], LOW);
delay(414);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[4], HIGH);
noteOff(0x90, 0x3E, 0);


//Bar 8
noteOn(0x90, 0x3C, 100); //Whole note: C
digitalWrite(LedR[2], HIGH);
digitalWrite(LedC[2], LOW);
delay(1656);
digitalWrite(LedR[2], LOW);
digitalWrite(LedC[2], HIGH);
noteOn(0x90, 0x3C, 0x00); //"Silent" note that makes sure the note stops playing.
delay(2000);
//End song
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, write a helper function so that you do not have so much repeated code, and call it for each note:

```
void playNote(int midi, int row, int col, int len)
{
    noteOn(0x90, midi, 100);
    digitalWrite(LedR[row], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LedC[col], LOW);
    delay(len);
    digitalWrite(LedR[row], LOW);
    digitalWrite(LedC[col], HIGH);
    noteOn(0x90, midi, 0x00);
}

...
//Bar 1
playNote(0x40, 3, 1, 414); //Quarter note: E
playNote(0x3e, 2, 4, 414); //Quarter note: D
...
```

Then, change it so that the note-off command and the LED switching can be done at different times:

```
void playNote(int midi, int row, int col, int len, bool short_led = false)
{
    int len1, len2;
    if (short_led) {
        len1 = len * 3 / 4;
        len2 = len * 1 / 4;
    } else {
        len1 = len;
        len2 = 0;
    }
    noteOn(0x90, midi, 100);
    digitalWrite(LedR[row], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LedC[col], LOW);
    delay(len1);
    digitalWrite(LedR[row], LOW);
    digitalWrite(LedC[col], HIGH);
    delay(len2);
    noteOn(0x90, midi, 0x00);
}
```

Comment: can you explain the use of the bool short  led?

Comment: wouldn't a second delay effect the timing of the notes?

Comment: Set `short_led` to make the LED light for a short time. The sum of `len1` and `len2` is always the same as `len`.

Comment: when i try to add a back button in the songlist function it dosent work

Comment: if (songpage==1){
     if (BackState==HIGH){//leaving song
      posP=0;
      Page=2; 
      Play(posP);
      }
    }

Comment: i want to be able to go back once the song starts playing to stop the song.

Comment: The back button has nothing to do with this question.